# Variance of truncated bivariate normal distribution related to bounds of truncation

Tags: convex-analysis, normal-distribution, variance

Consider pdf of a bivariate normal distribution as follow:

$f(x,y)=\phi(x-z)\,\beta\, \phi(\beta(x+y))$,

where $\phi$ is PDF of standard normal distribution.

How can we show the truncated variance $Var(X| X<v, Y>2v)$ is increasing in $v$.

Numerically, I can show the variance is increasing in $v$.

Comment: $\beta$ is related to correlation $\beta>0$. $z$ can be any number. It is related to the mean.

Comment: I can show numerically that $Log[\frac{Pr(X<w,Y>2w)}{Pr(X<w-\epsilon,Y>2(w-\epsilon))}]$ is convex and increasing in $z$, which can be shown to be equivalent to showing $Var(X|X<w,Y>2w)>Var(X|X<w-\epsilon,Y>2(w-\epsilon))$.

Comment: Define $F=\int_{-\infty}^w\int_{2w}^\infty\, f(x,y)dy\,dx$. Then we need to show $\frac{d^2\, Log F}{dz^2}-\left(\frac{d\, Log F}{dz}\right)^2$ is increasing in $w$.

Answer (score 0):

Define 
\begin{align*}
F=\int_0^{\infty}\int_{0}^\infty \beta \phi(\beta(x+y+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, dy d x 
\end{align*}
where $\beta>0$ and $z$ are some parameters.

Define random variables $(X,Y)$ defined for positive values with the probability distribution function $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{F}\beta \phi(\beta(x+y+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)$. Throughout this proof, we use the symbol $E$ as the expected value operator with respect to distribution of $(X,Y)$.

It is easy to verify that

\begin{align*}
&\partial_z \log(F)=v-z-\mu_x\\
&\partial_{z,z}\log(F)=-1+\sigma_x^2
\end{align*}
where, $\mu_x$ and $\sigma^2_x$ are  mean and variance of random variable $X$ and depend on parameters $v$ and $z$. Specifically, $\mu_x=\frac{1}{F}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{0}^\infty x \beta \phi(\beta(x+y+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d y d x $ and $\sigma^2_x=\frac{1}{F}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{0}^\infty (x-\mu_x)^2 \beta \phi(\beta(x+y+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d y d x $.

We can verify that the main problem is reduced to showing $\partial_{z,z,v} F>0$.

Define $\mu_t$ as expected value of the $X+Y$. We can evaluate $\mu_t$ as follow:
\begin{align*}
\mu_t&=\frac{1}{F}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{0}^\infty (x+y) \beta \phi(\beta(x+y+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d y d x \\
&=-v-\frac{1}{\beta^2 F}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{0}^\infty  \beta \phi'(\beta(x+y+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d y d x\\
&=-v+\frac{1}{\beta^2 F} \int_{0}^\infty \beta \phi(\beta(x+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d x
\end{align*}
Hence, $\beta^2(v+\mu_t)=\frac{1}{ F} \int_{0}^\infty \beta \phi(\beta(x+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d x$, that we use below.

Since, $\partial_{z,z}\log(F)=-1+\sigma_x^2$, from definition of $\sigma^2_x$, 
\begin{align*}
\partial_{z,z,v}\log(F)&=\partial_v \sigma_x^2=E\left[(X-\mu_x)^3-\beta^2 (X-\mu_x)^2(X+Y-\mu_t) \right]\\
&=E\left[(X-\mu_x)^3-\beta^2 (X-\mu_x)^2(X+Y+v-v-\mu_t) \right]
\end{align*}
We expand parts of this expectation as follow
\begin{align*}
&\beta^2 E\left[\beta^2 (x-\mu_x)^2(v+\mu_t)\right]=\sigma_x^2\beta^2(v+\mu_t)=\sigma_x^2\frac{1}{F}  \int_{0}^\infty \beta \phi(\beta(x+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d x\\
&E[\beta^2 (x-\mu_x)^2(x+y+v)]=\frac{1}{F}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{0}^\infty -(x-\mu_x)^2 \beta \phi'(\beta(x+y+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d y d x\\
&=\frac{1}{F}\int_0^{\infty} (x-\mu_x)^2 \beta \phi(\beta(x+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d x
\end{align*}

Let $f_y(y)$ be marginal distribution of $Y$. Notice that $f_y(0)=\frac{1}{F}\int_0^{\infty} \beta \phi(\beta(x+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d x$. Also notice that $ \frac{\beta \phi(\beta(x+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\,}{\int_0^{\infty} \beta \phi(\beta(x+v))\,\phi(x-v+z)\, d x}$ is the conditional probability distribution function of $X$ given $Y=0$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
E\left[-\beta^2 (X-\mu_x)^2(X+Y+v-v-\mu_t) \right]=f_y(0)\left(-E[(X-\mu_x)^2|Y=0]+E[(X-\mu_x)^2]\right)
\end{align*}

Hence, 
\begin{align*}
\partial_{z,z,v}\log(F)=E\left[(X-\mu_x)^3\right]+f_y(0)(-E[(X-\mu_x)^2|Y=0]+E[(X-\mu_x)^2])
\end{align*}

Notice that $(X,Y)$ are truncated bivariate normal distribution with a negative correlation. Hence conditional distribution of $(X|Y=0)$ second order stochastically dominates marginal distribution of $X$. Then since $(x-\mu_x)^2$ is convex in $x$, we must have $E[(x-\mu_x)^2]>E[(x-\mu_x)^2|Y=0]$. Also, since $(X,Y)$ are truncated from below, we must have $E\left[(x-\mu_x)^3\right]>0$. In conclusion, $\partial_{z,z,v}\log(F)>0$.

(The last two claims can be written more rigorously!)